# Как сделать, чтобы Dropdown на Boostrap всегда был открыт

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток, Столкнулся с 2 проблемами.

1. При нажатии на Slide кнопку в мобильной версии сайта необходимо,
   чтобы Dropdown menu всегда был открыт.
2. При нажатии на Slide кнопку,
   текст внутри как бы выстраивается, а должен выезжать без
   выстраивания, как в примере по которому делал https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navbar-lateral-slide-menu

HTML

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse-side" data-target=".side-collapse" data-target-2=".side-collapse-container">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="color: #f8f0d2;">TITLE</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="navbar-inverse side-collapse in">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nabvbar-menu">
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Something there</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Something there</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something there</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Something there</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Личный кабинет</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something there</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Выход</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

CSS

```
.dropdown {
right: 15px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
width: 230px;
}

#login-dp{
min-width: 250px;
padding: 14px 14px 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}

#login-dp .help-block {
font-size: 12px
}

#login-dp .bottom {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
clear: both;
padding: 14px;
}

#login-dp .social-buttons {
margin: 12px 0
}

#login-dp .social-buttons a {
width: 49%;
}

#login-dp .form-group {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
#login-dp{
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #fff;
}
#login-dp .bottom{
    background-color: inherit;
    border-top: 0 none;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-toggle {
    left: 10px;
}
.side-collapse-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    transition: left .4s;
}
.side-collapse-container.out {
    left: 200px;
}
.side-collapse {
    background: black;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width .4s;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
.side-collapse.navbar-right {
    height: 100px;
}
.side-collapse.navbar-right.dropdown {

}
.side-collapse.in {
    width: 0;
}
.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-brand {

}
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-side]'),
    sel1 = sideslider.attr('data-target'),
    sel2 = sideslider.attr('data-target-2');

  sideslider.click(function(event){
    $(sel1).toggleClass('in');
    $(sel2).toggleClass('out');
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zg8wLdc8/4/

Comment: фрагменты кода нужно добавлять на SO

Comment: @Alex78191  
при нажатии на Личный кабинет появляется другой Личный кабинет

Comment: Обновил ответ на вопрос

Comment: @Alex78191 как можно расстояние между блоками ЛК и Навбаром сократить до минимума? Чтобы эти блоки выглядели как единый блок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (max-width:768px) {

  .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
  }

  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
  }
}
```